# Get recent threads that the user did not join in to

Tags: mysql

We're trying to simply list recent threads from a table that the user in question hasn't joined in to yet.

The code below does not work (shows both new threads **and** threads that the user already joined in to), but shows what tables we're using:

```
SELECT t.*, jt.*
FROM thread t 
INNER JOIN joined_threads jt ON jt.thread_id = t.unique_id
WHERE t.owner != '$user_id'
AND jt.saved_by != '$user_id' 
GROUP BY t.unique_id
```

Used tables:

```
THREAD:
unique_id
owner
title
content
date
```

and

```
JOINED_THREADS:
saved_by
thread_id
```

I presume this is very easy for most of you :)

Comment: Any specifics of what's wrong with the query you have?

Comment: Simply doesn't show the correct records. It shows both threads I've joined as well as new ones I haven't.

Comment: Not sure, I am no sql expert, but I think that the problem is that you will only get one joined_thread record per thread due to the inner join

Comment: Which field stores that a user has joined a thread? `thread.owner`? Or `joined_threads.saved_by` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you need

```
SELECT t.*, jt.*
FROM thread t 
LEFT JOIN joined_threads jt ON jt.thread_id = t.unique_id AND jt.saved_by = '$user_id' 
WHERE t.owner <> '$user_id' AND jt.thread_id is NULL
GROUP BY t.unique_id
```

(not tested). Btw what for do you need jt.*, would be always NULL

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM thread t
WHERE t.owner <> '$user_id'
  AND NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM joined_threads jt
        WHERE jt.thread_id = t.unique_id
          AND jt.saved_by = '$user_id' 
      )
```