# Mysql Getting mutliple collections and their latest image from a database using one query

Tags: mysql

Any kind soul that can help me retreive latest published image in a bucket (collection) to show instead of the first posted? The code below works, that would love the show the latest added image instead of the first added in the database.

Here is the MySQL query I'm using:

```
        SELECT t.*, bt.*, d.* 
        FROM collection_images bt, collections t, images d 
        WHERE bt.collection_id = t.unique_id 
        AND (t.creator IN ($dropper_id))
        AND d.unique_id = bt.image_id 
        GROUP BY bt.collection_id
```

Here are the tables:

*collections*

```
id
name
unique_id
creator
```

*collection_images*

```
id
collection_id
unique_id
image_id
```

*images*

```
id
image_url
unique_id
title
date
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is the significance of having both id and unique_id in each of your tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten the query -

```
SELECT c.*, images.*
FROM collections c
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT collection_id, MAX(images.id) AS max_id
    FROM collection_images
    INNER JOIN images
        ON collection_images.image_id = images.unique_id
    GROUP BY collection_id
) AS latest
    ON c.unique_id = latest.collection_id
INNER JOIN images
    ON latest.max_id = images.id
WHERE (c.creator IN ($dropper_id))
```

**UPDATE** now using images.id instead of images.date as the second join to collection_images is then not needed.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately unique_id is used for creating a unique string for all images, and there is not MAX for this.

Comment: Is there a reason for not using a unique auto_incrementing id for each entity? Is date a DATETIME field?

Comment: We've been using this unique_id for a long time, and really tricky to re-write the whole thing now, but you’re so true, we could have used the auto-inc for unique id. Yes, date is Datetime. Also have time for Timestamp if that helps.

Comment: What is stored in id field? Are the collection_id and image_id in the join table referencing the unique_ids as opposed to ids? Ignore my last update.

Comment: in "collection_images":"image_id" checks for "images":"unique_id".The ID fields are all auto-inc num as they are suppose to be used. But the whole project is based on the unique_ids I'm afraid. :S

Comment: nnichols! Thank you _very_ much! You saved my day. Seriously.

Comment: Are both date and id sequential in the images table? If so I will use id instead of date as it should be slightly faster depending on how the table is indexed.

Comment: they are ;) just tried your code above and it works. But of course, faster is better !

Comment: Please click on the tick to accept the answer if it is working as you would like. Also the same for your previous question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137793/get-recent-threads-that-the-user-did-not-join-in-to

Comment: I have modified the query to use images.id instead of date as you can then do away with the second join to collection_images

Comment: Thank you once again nnichols!

Answer (score 0):

you can try order images.id desc also i am not sure your date field what it store ?
if timestamp then you can use this.

Comment: Already tried it I'm afraid. Added `ORDER by image.id DESC` after `GROUP BY` without luck.